# Show sharedpreference inside RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android

I have problem to pass context from Activity to Adapter.

I am calling my sharedpreference like this:

```
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    String userObject = pref.getString(key, null);
```

And this one need context, so i am using : `getApplicationContext()`

But this not work in the Adapter (RecyclerView), is there someone facing the same issue ?

Adding the adapter into the Manifest file will solve the problem ? (Just a suggestion)

Comment: This is what I did. (If you cant access class "context" inside SharedPreferences)
1. Create a context of the adapter class by " Context mConext"; or "private WeakReference<Context> mContext;"
2. Instead giving "mContext" use "this.mContext.get()" wherever you need to use context inside the SharedPrefernce. like
SharedPreferences preferences = this.mContext.get().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

I tried somany other solutions, but could'nt find the thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking but here is a solution that I can think of.
Pass the context of the calling activity in your adapter through constructor and then use that context.

```
Context ctx;

public YourAdapter(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

now in your adapter you can do this

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
String userObject = pref.getString(key, null);
```

Comment: contextThatYouProvided is the problem here, i need use it inside the adapter.

Comment: Pass it to the adapter through the adapter constructor. Then use it in adapter.

Comment: How to pass it here: `public class AdapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` ?

Comment: the constructor should be something like this 'public AdapterList (Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter create constructor with `Context` like this,

```
public AdapterList(Context ctx){
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    String userObject = pref.getString(key, null);
}
```

and create it by passing

```
    adapter = new YourAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I need using context inside the adapter and not in the activity it self.

Comment: My adapter is a class: `public class AdapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`

Comment: where did you create your adapter?, put the `Context` in your adapter's constructor

Comment: I created my adapter in a new class, and call it from the activity. How to do that in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to separate your preference-managing code into singleton class so you can get access to the preferences anywhere, just like this

```
public class SharedPreferenceManager {
private static final SharedPreferenceManager ourInstance = new SharedPreferenceManager();

public static SharedPreferenceManager getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private SharedPreferenceManager() {
}

private SharedPreferences preferences;

public void init(Context ctx) {
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
}

public String getValueByKey(String key) {
    return preferences.getString(key, "");
}..other functions....}
```

you should call the `SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance().init(this)` in your onCreate() in the activity

and after you can get access to SP wherever you want: `SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance().getValueByKey("somekey")`